# weird postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I could not make sense of a query, I found a workaround to get the data but I would like to know what happened.

so basically I want to obtain all ids that are not contained in another table. if I count them separately I get this:

```
select count(distinct product_sid) 
from gaps_inp.pim_product_channel pc 
where pc.channel_code = 'Amazon'
```

> ### count
>
> 200658

and then count items on the other table:

```
select count(w.sid)
from gaps_fend.product_whitelist w 
where w.channel_code  = 'Amazon'
```

> ### count
>
> 39697

but now if I try to count the difference:

```
select count(*) 
from gaps_inp.pim_product_channel pc 
where pc.channel_code = 'Amazon' 
and pc.product_sid not in (
  select w.sid
  from gaps_fend.product_whitelist w 
  where w.channel_code  = 'Amazon'
);
```

> ### count
>
> 0

both fields **gaps_inp.pim_product_channel.product_sid** and **gaps_fend.product_whitelist.sid** are **bigint**

I was able to do it by using a **left join** and a **where sid is null**, but still I would like to know what I did wrong in the **where not in**  query.

this is the workaround:

```
select count(distinct pc.product_sid)
from gaps_inp.pim_product_channel pc 
left join gaps_fend.product_whitelist w on w.channel_code = 'Amazon' and pc.product_sid = w.sid
where pc.channel_code = 'Amazon'
and w.sid is null;
```

> ### count
>
> 160968

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am sure there are some `NULL` values present in below query

```
select w.sid
from gaps_fend.product_whitelist w 
where w.channel_code  = 'Amazon'
```

`NOT IN` fails when the `sub-query` returns any `NULL` values so you are getting zero count. So the work around is using `LEFT JOIN` or `NOT EXISTS` or adding `IS NOT NULL` condition in `sub-query`

`NOT EXISTS` method which can handle `NULL` values

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   gaps_inp.pim_product_channel pc
WHERE  pc.channel_code = 'Amazon'
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM   gaps_fend.product_whitelist w
                       WHERE  w.channel_code = 'Amazon'
                              AND w.sid = pc.product_sid);
```

Comment: I missed your answer when I answered.

Answer (score 0):

`not in` returns no rows if there is a NULL value returned by the sub-query.
Add `and w.sid is not null`